# map is not visible in OpenStreetMap (osm)

Tags: java, android, api, openstreetmap, osmdroid

My goal is it to build a simple app for android. The app needs some map data from OpenStreetMap (OSM). I made the decision to use osmdroid for my litle project. and now I am close to the result I want to see, there is just one small difficulty for me. If I try to run the app now there is no mistake (exceptions or errors) but unfortunately I don't see a map:

[image: empty osm view]

My guess is that my commandline in the `@Override public void onCreate()` class is needed. but if I remove the commandline and make it to "real code" there is an error with the method `getInstance().load(...)` so my thoughts are that there is something wrong with my `Configuration` class. there are no suggestion for my code to find/remove the error

thats my MainActivity.java class:

````
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MapView map = null;
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        //Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        map.onResume();
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        map.onPause();
    }

}```
````

Comment: What exact error are you receiving at `Configuration.getInstance().load()`?

Comment: `error: cannot find symbol
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the anwser by myself. The mistake was the wrong import. `import android.content.res.Configuration;`
This is the correct one: `import org.osmdroid.config.Configuration;`
my actual mainActivity looks like this now:

````
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import org.osmdroid.config.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MapView map = null;
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();

        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);



        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(13);

        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(52.516181, 13.376935);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        map.onResume();
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        map.onPause();
    }



}```
````